# Robot Framework POST Request using RequestsLibrary passing wrong arguments

Tags: xml, http-post, httprequest, robotframework

**Context**

Using the RequestsLibrary to automate tests for sending XML Post Requests to a server and receiving a Response which should be validated.

The test currently Gets the 'payload' of an XML file and attempts to pass this as the 'data' argument for a Post Request.

**The error**

Using the RequestsLibrary on Robot Framework, the POST request continually leads to

```
<Response [500]>
```

and

```
Page can either not be found or displayed. <br />
Please try again or return to login.
```

within the repsonse body.

**The problem**

The response code we're looking for is of course 200 however 500 is continually received. Hence the response body contains

```
Page can either not be found or displayed. <br />
Please try again or return to login.
```

and not the required XML response, something like

```
><MsgType>ERROR</MsgType>
<MsgData>&lt;ERROR&gt;&lt;CODE&gt;0110&lt;/CODE&gt;&lt;MSGTXT&gt;Encryption 
Failure&lt;/MSGTXT&gt;&lt;/ERROR&gt;</MsgData></ProcessMsgResult>
</ProcessMsgResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

which should be the sort of response for an invalid request.

**The Code**

```
Post request XML payload
    Disable Warnings
    Create Session    Gateway    https://URLHERE    debug=3
    ${file_data}=    Get Binary File    ${CURDIR}${/}text.xml
    &{headers}=    Create Dictionary    Content-Type    text/xml
    ${resp}=    Post Request    Gateway    /post    data=${file_data}    headers=${headers}
    Log    ${resp.text}
    Log    ${resp.status_code}
    Should Be Equal As Strings    ${resp.status_code}    200
```

This is the code I am running with the Post Request arguments for `data` as `${file_data}` and `headers` as `${headers}`. **However, from the test run report, the  `${file_data}` isn't being passed down correctly to the Post Request Keyword because it's using the `<text/xml>` as the data argument and not `${file_data}`**

```
INFO : Post Request using : alias=Gateway, uri=/post, data=<text/xml>, headers={u'Content-Type': u'text/xml'}, files=None, allow_redirects=True
```

This is where the problem lies, and I'm not sure why for the data argument it's always `data=<text/xml>`.

**Question**

**Has anyone encountered this issue before of the argument not being passed down correctly?** As I believe it should be `data=<${file_data>`, the 500 response would no longer be received because the server would receive an understandable XML request.

Comment: The issue most probably comes from the server - its response is a semi-generic 500 error; does it require authentication - this might be the case with this wording? This is very app-specific, and as you probably can't share the actual url nor the API protocol in this public forum, you have to look for the issue yourself. Also, don't presume the file's content is not in the request - this is just how it gets to the log, judging by the lib's source (the class method `_format_data_to_log_string_according_to_header`). It shouldn't be logging the full file anyway - what if it was 5MB big?

Comment: File only 2KB. Okay, thanks for the suggestion regarding authentication. Will look into this. And, I see, with the class method as '_format_data_to_log_string_according_to_header'  the log shows the data as the header name.

Comment: Did it work with auth?

Comment: unfortunately auth isn't the problem. i believe it's in the XML payload. server not liking the actual XML request.

Answer (score -1):

I was also getting the same response code 500 while using the same keywords.

**The correct solution which worked for me was -**

Create Session    iamconnected    http://10.204.17.117:8085/
${Request_Header}    Create Dictionary    Content-Type=text/xml; charset=utf-8
${Request_Body}    Get File    IF1021VE.xml
${resp}    Post Request    iamconnected    Runner/services    ${Request_Body}  headers=${Request_Header}

So in this code , the fully qualified URL was - http://10.204.17.117:8085/Runner/services

Runner/services is the **params** which I have passed.

I am using pre-built Operating System Library for **Get File** for getting the contents from XML file

iamconnected is my alias.

RequestsHeader is my header

**Note : While I was using Dictionary as it is mentioned in Requests Library page , I was getting the same server response code 500**

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: by using dictionary , we get server response code 500 , we need 200 for successful connection , and there is change in url also , the basic url needs to be there in Create session .That's how it can help

Answer (score -1):

#### Incorrect

```
Create Session      aliasName   url=http://address/sub1/sub2/sub3
${resp}=    Post Request  alias=aliasName   uri=/  data=${file_data}   headers=${headers}
```

#### Correct

```
Create Session      aliasName   url=http://address/
${resp}=    Post Request  alias=aliasName   uri=sub1/sub2/sub3  data=${file_data}   headers=${headers}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please edit your answer and explain!